# Add input fields in form when dropdown option selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

How to add fields in form dynamically

so my form looks like :

```
<form action="/reservation-add" method="post">
<select id="dropdownlist">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<input></input>
</form>
```

If selected e.g 3 it should append 3 new inputs (could be array to take all of values ) I know that I have to use javascript but I don't know how.

Comment: need to add text inputs?

Comment: yes it will contain name

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change, http://api.jquery.com/append

Comment: There's no `</input>`!

Comment: @PraveenKumar ah thats right it was just to show where it should append

Comment: he don't even know javscript. all answers in jquery

Comment: pls go through the http://www.w3schools.com/js/ tutorials

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this way:

```
$("#dropdownlist").change(function () {
    var numInputs = $(this).val();
    for (var i = 0; i < numInputs; i++)
        $("#inputArea").append('<input name="inputs[]" />');
});
```

Have another `div`, with the ID "inputArea":

```
<div id="inputArea"></div>
```

**Snippet**

```js
$("#dropdownlist").change(function () {
  var numInputs = $(this).val();
  for (var i = 0; i < numInputs; i++)
    $("#inputArea").append('<input name="inputs[]" />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdownlist">
  <option>Select...</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<div id="inputArea"></div>
```

Comment: thanks !! i just added clean up previous selected from other post and it works as i thought

Comment: since you're using `.append`, even if you change your dropdown selection, it doesn't get rid of the previous boxes. You can empty the element with `.empty().append()` or just overwrite the HTML element using `.html('<input name="inputs[]" />)`

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="/reservation-add" method="post" id="appendform">
  <select id="dropdownlist">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<input></input>
</form>
```

Jquery Code

```
  $(document).ready(function ()
 {
  $('#dropdownlist').on('change',function ()
  {
    var howmuch = $(this).val();
    var appendhtml = '';
    for (i = 0; i < howmuch; i++)
    { 
        appendhtml+= "<input name="+i+" value="">";
    }
    $('.appendform').append(appendhtml);
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#dropdownlist").on("change",function(e){
    for(i=0; i < $(this).val() ;i++){
        $("form").append($("<input type='text'/>"));
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**--- Add id to form
**Step 2**---Use jquery onchange method, code shown below

```
<form action="/reservation-add" method="post" id="myForm">
    <select id="dropdownlist">
        <option value="1"></option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</form>

$('#dropdownlist').on("change",function() {
          for(var i=0;i&lt;this.value;i++)
          {
              $("#myForm").append("<input type='text' name='myname[]'/>
               <br>");
          }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
    function fireChange(val) {
    var form = document.forms[0];
        if(val) {
            for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
                var in = document.createElement('input');
                form.appendChild(in);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<form action="/reservation-add" method="post" onchange="fireChange(this.value)">
<select id="dropdownlist">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<input></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get around the problem of adding yet more input fields after the initial drop down selection (if the user changes their mind after the initial selection), which is the case with all the answers on this page.
See the solution below:

```
$("#dropdownlist").change(function () {
  $("#inputArea > :input").remove();
  var numInputs = $(this).val();
  for (var i = 0; i < numInputs; i++)
    $("#inputArea").append('<input name="inputs[]" />');
});
```

Comment: @binar Tx, thought it might help someone. Please upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By pure JavaScript, you can do it like this;

```
<script>
document.getElementById("dropdown").onchange = function() {
    document.querySelector("#inputarea").innerHTML = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("dropdown").value; i++) {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.name = 'input_name';
        input.type = 'text';
        document.getElementById("inputarea").append(input);
    }
}
</script>
```

And here is the html;

```
<body>
<form>
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="inputarea"></div>
</body>
```